# How to get all has_many objects in all model instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the `Event` model. It `has_many :participants`.

Can do `Event.all.each do |event|` and then try to manipulate `event.participants`

But is there an easier way to get all participants for all events?

It's a typical problem in OO when you get an Array of "Events" back not an EventArray with the right methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can get `Participants` that are part of any `Event` like this

```
Participant.where(event_id: Event.pluck(:id))
```

or just

```
Participant.all
```

if there are no `Participants` without an associated `Event`

Answer (score 1):

`Participant.joins(:event)` should get you all the participants in an event.

Answer (score 1):

`Event.joins(:participants).select("participants.*")` 
This will give all participants which are associated with event

Answer (score -1):

you can use `eager_load` and `group_by` in this issue. In your case

```
event = Event.eager_load(:participants).group_by(&:participants)
```

it will create a Hash of all events with associated participants. you can access  0 index for participants and 1 index for that event. Something like

```
event.first[0] = all the participants of that event
event.first[1] = that event
```